# Integrating Facebook login with native login system

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I currently run a web application that has its own native registration and login system.

Now I would like to add Facebook login to my site, and integrate it with my native registration system. Like check the email returned from Facebook, and add the user to the database with a flag indicating he is a Facebook user, and then just authenticate the user.

While I have some idea of how to implement the system, I would like inputs on whether I should use the Facebook SDK for JavaScript, or the server-side SDK. I see that Facebook recommends the JavaScript SDK for WebApps. However in case of integrating with a native system, will it be the ideal choice? I believe the JavaScript SDK would work good when the login is purely Facebook, and is meant for simple authentication-required views.

Can someone who has worked with Facebook login help with this decision?

Answer (score 0):

You are right integrating Facebook Javascript SDK will not be a good choice for Native log-in system as in any case you will have to pass some input(userid) to your server side program like facebook ID/email id to synchronize the user with your native system, from javascript. Which will be a 3 way channel > Facebook - JS(user browser) - Your Server, this makes it less secure as someone with user id can ping your server and it will log the user in.

I was also working on same scenario where I need to enable users to login with Facebook as an option. However a native login system was deeply integrated with the application. So I used PHP SDK inspite of JS SDK.